# error with changing a div background with javascript after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, refresh, background-image

I'm trying to setup a script that will change the background of a DIV with each page fresh.
This is my code.

Untitled Document

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
var totalCount = 3;
function ChangeIt()
{
var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );

document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundImage = "url('bgimages/'"+num+"'.jpg')";}
</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="content">

hello
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
ChangeIt();

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that it's not changing and I'm getting this error:
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a couple of extra quotes in "url('bgimages/'"+num+"'.jpg')", try "url(bgimages/"+num+".jpg)"

Comment: thanks!! I knew it was going to be something simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("content").style.backgroundImage = "url('bgimages/"+num+".jpg')";}
```